# Writing a function with a domain that is a finite range of integers

Tags: function-construction, conditional

I want to write a conditional function defined for $n=[-5:5]$. Explicitly,

$\qquad Z_n=A e^{ikn}+Be^{-ikn}$ for $n\leq1$ and  $Z_n=T e^{ikn}$ for $n\geq2$.

I have written it but it is not very neat and hard to use elsewhere. Can it be written in a better way so could be easy to use in another code? I wrote it as

```
n = {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
nn = {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1};
mm = {2, 3, 4, 5};
a = A*E^(I*k*nn) + B*E^(-I*k*nn) %for n<=1
b = T*E^(I*k*mm)                 %for n>=2
```

Comment: Have a look at `Piecewise`.

Comment: Have a look too at *Mathematica's* basic documentation on how to write functions.  A lot of folk here will look at your 'code' and think *that's not how to write Mathematica functions, in fact it's so far from being the way I balk at explaining how wrong it is*.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Thanks. Something like this? `n = {-5, -4, -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
pw = Piecewise[{{A*E^(I*k*n) + B*E^(-I*k*n), n <= 1}, {T*E^(I*k*n), 
    n >= 2}}]`

Comment: As suggested by @HighPerformanceMark, please read [DefiningFunctions)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html).

Comment: @b.gatessucks Ok. I got this working now, but how do I tie it to a vector? i.e., how do I fix this function 'pw[n_]' to take values only from a vector, say x=[-5,5]? 'pw[n_] := 
 Piecewise[{{A*E^(I*k*n) + B*E^(-I*k*n), n <= 1}, {T*E^(I*k*n), 
    n >= 2}}]'

Comment: How about this? `pw /@ Range[-5, 5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If k, aa, bb, and tt (best not to use capital letters to avoid collisions with Mathematica-defined terms) are currently just unassigned symbols, or if they are permanent constants, you can memoize them.

```
Table[zz[n] = aa E^(I k n) + bb E^(-I k n), {n, -5, 1}];
Table[zz[n] = tt E^(I k n), {n, 2, 5}];
```

Printing them out...

```
Table[{zz[n]}, {n, -5, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{c}
 e^{-5 i k} \text{aa}+\text{bb} e^{5 i k} \\
 e^{-4 i k} \text{aa}+\text{bb} e^{4 i k} \\
 e^{-3 i k} \text{aa}+\text{bb} e^{3 i k} \\
 e^{-2 i k} \text{aa}+\text{bb} e^{2 i k} \\
 e^{-i k} \text{aa}+\text{bb} e^{i k} \\
 \text{aa}+\text{bb} \\
 e^{i k} \text{aa}+\text{bb} e^{-i k} \\
 e^{2 i k} \text{tt} \\
 e^{3 i k} \text{tt} \\
 e^{4 i k} \text{tt} \\
 e^{5 i k} \text{tt} \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: Y  Thank you very much!..

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the function to return unevaluated for values of `n` that do not meet the conditions:

```
ClearAll[Z];

Z[n_Integer?(-5 <= # <= 1 &)] :=
  A*Exp[I*k*n] + B*Exp[-I*k*n];
Z[n_Integer?(2 <= # <= 5 &)] := T*Exp[I*k*n];
```

For example,

```
Z /@ {-6, -3., -3, 3, 3., 6}

(* {Z[-6], Z[-3.], A E^(-3 I k) + B E^(3 I k), E^(3 I k) T, Z[3.], Z[6]} *)
```

If you want the function to return unevaluated and an error message for values of `n` that do not meet the conditions:

```
ClearAll[Z]

Z::argni = 
  "The argument `1` is not an integer in the closed interval {-5, 5}.";

Z[n_] /; If[TrueQ[Element[n, Integers] && -5 <= n <= 5],
    True, Message[Z::argni, n]; False] :=
  Piecewise[{{A*Exp[I*k*n] + B*Exp[-I*k*n], -5 <= n <= 1}},
   T*Exp[I*k*n]];
```

For example,

```
Z /@ {-6, -3., -3, 3, 3., 6}
```

[image]

```
(* {Z[-6], Z[-3.], A E^(-3 I k) + B E^(3 I k), E^(3 I k) T, Z[3.], Z[6]} *)
```

If you want the function to evaluate to zero for values of `n` that do not meet the conditions:

```
ClearAll[Z];

Z[n_] := Piecewise[{
    {A*Exp[I*k*n] + B*Exp[-I*k*n], IntegerQ[n] && -5 <= n <= 1},
    {T*Exp[I*k*n],
     IntegerQ[n] && 2 <= n <= 5}}];
```

For example,

```
Z /@ {-6, -3., -3, 3, 3., 6}

(* {0, 0, A E^(-3 I k) + B E^(3 I k), E^(3 I k) T, 0, 0} *)
```

Comment: Thank you !.....

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `A`, `B` and `T` are given constants and the `k` is an integer parameter, you could write

```
With[{A = 1, B = 2, T = 3},
  z[k_Integer][n_Integer /; MemberQ[Range[-5, 5], n]] :=
     Piecewise[{{A E^(I k n) + B E^(-I k n), n <= 1}, {T E^(I k n), n >= 2}}]]
```

I have given arbitrary values to `A`, `B` and `T` because you didn't define them; you should substitute your actual value for these parameters.

Now let's test `z` over your domain for a few values of `k`.

```
Table[z[k] /@ Range[-5, 5], {k, 3}]
```

> ```
> {{E^(-5 I) + 2 E^(5 I), E^(-4 I) + 2 E^(4 I), E^(-3 I) + 2 E^(3 I), E^(-2 I) + 2 E^(2 I), 
>   E^-I + 2 E^I, 3, 2 E^-I + E^I, 3 E^(2 I), 3 E^(3 I), 3 E^(4 I), 3 E^(5 I)}, 
>  {E^(-10 I) + 2 E^(10 I), E^(-8 I) + 2 E^(8 I), E^(-6 I) + 2 E^(6 I), E^(-4 I) + 2 E^(4 I), 
>   E^(-2 I) + 2 E^(2 I), 3, 2 E^(-2 I) + E^(2 I), 3 E^(4 I), 3 E^(6 I), 3 E^(8 I), 3 E^(10 I)}, 
>  {E^(-15 I) + 2 E^(15 I), E^(-12 I) + 2 E^(12 I), E^(-9 I) + 2 E^(9 I), E^(-6 I) + 2 E^(6 I), 
>   E^(-3 I) + 2 E^(3 I), 3, 2 E^(-3 I) + E^(3 I), 3 E^(6 I), 3 E^(9 I), 3 E^(12 I), 3 E^(15 I)}}
> ```

But `z` won't accept integers outside the interval {-5, 5}>

```
z[2][11]
```

> `z[2][11]`

#### Update

This is my 2nd thought on implementing `z`. It should have been my first thought given that the integer range comprising the domain is a simple sequence and not a disjoint collection of integers.

```
With[{A = 1, B = 2, T = 3}, 
  z[k_Integer][n_Integer /; -5 <= n <= 5] := 
    Piecewise[{{A E^(I k n) + B E^(-I k n), n <= 1}, {T E^(I k n), n >= 2}}]]
```

This is more concise, more succinct and more efficient than 1st thought on the matter.

Comment: Many Thanks! ......